# Topbar sometimes detaches from the top

Tags: bug, design, top-bar

*Sometimes* (not always) while browsing Stack Exchange I notice that top bar tries to escape its position, and an annoying margin appears:

[image]

It is not really predictable. It could happen when I check achievements or notifications, it could happen while scrolling, also happened to me when I clicked to ask this question.

That said, no custom settings. Latest Safari on iOS 15.4. Browser zoom 100%.

I believe it’s a “sub-pixel rendering” issue caused by the super-high resolution screen (which it is on the most of flagship smartphones of recent years)

Comment: [Bruh ](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1DHaY.jpg)

Comment: I think it's the browser border

Comment: @arc nope that’s wrong

Comment: I honestly can't see any bug here. It's just a margin, common thing in design. Nothing is being "detached" anywhere.

Comment: @sha there should be no margin at all, normally it looks [this way](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lXpsm.jpg)

Comment: When you say "this way" in your link there is a margin, faint but definitely there.

Comment: I really don't see any difference and even if there is some pixels of extra margin, so what?? It still look the same. It's there, it didn't fall down. This is super neat picking, while valid I just disagree there's any bug here.

Comment: @sha I’m a little bit confused - I would say the difference is pretty noticeable. Are you from mobile or desktop?

Comment: I mean, the gap is large enough so as there’s clearly [text peaking from underneath](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bu0G2.jpg)

Comment: I'm on desktop but talking about your screenshots. Also can't see any text peaking in your last screenshot. Maybe just my bad eyes, really no idea. :/

Comment: @ShadowWizardSaysNoMoreWar (Sorry, couldn’t resist.) You mean super *nitpicking*.

Comment: @EmilJeřábek you nitpick my nitpicking! How nitpicky of you. :-D